# SELECT query when number of where conditions are not fixed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have the following requirement. I have four fields Company Name, Experience,
Salary From, Salary To. Now I want user to enter any field he wants and the SELECT query will be fired based on user's input so for example if user enters only Experience and Salary From entries then the result would be to display all records which matches the entered experience and whose starting salary range is greater than entered salary from.

```
if(isset($_GET["btnSubmit"])){

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jobportal");

$company = $_GET['txtCompanyName'];
$experience = $_GET["txtExperience"];
$salaryFrom = $_GET["txtSalaryFrom"];
$salaryTo = $_GET["txtSalaryTo"];

//$sql = ?
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

$raw_results = $stmt->fetch_array();
if($raw_results[0] > 0){

     //$sql=?
     $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    while($results = $stmt->fetch_array()){ 
        echo "<p><h3>".$results[0]."</h3>".$results[1]."</p>";
    }

}
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    echo "No results";
}


<form action="" method="get">
                     <p>
                        <label for="companyname" class="icon-user">     Company Name
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtCompanyName" placeholder="Company Name" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="experience" class="icon-pencil"> Experience
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtExperience" placeholder="Experience"/>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="salaryfrom" class="icon-pencil"> Salary From
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtSalaryFrom" placeholder="Salary Starting Range"/>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="salaryto" class="icon-pencil"> Salary To
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtSalaryTo" placeholder="Salary End Range"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
                    </p>
                 </form>
```

Comment: usually: where (thefield = user_argument or user_argument is null) or (...)

Comment: And.. Can you show us your PHP Code ? You should just use IF

Comment: @Aks Entered the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your SQL query dynamically based on the post

```
   $form = $_GET;

    $where = "1=1 ";

    // Check the second input
    if(isset($form["txtSalaryFrom"]) and is_numeric($form["txtSalaryFrom"])) {
        $where. = "and u.salary >= :txtSalaryFrom";
    }
    // Check the first input
    if(isset($form["txtSalaryTo"]) and is_numeric($form["txtSalaryTo"])) {
        $where. = "and u.salary < :txtSalaryTo ";
    }

    if(isset($form["txtCompanyName"])) {
    $where. = "and u.txtCompanyName like :txtCompanyName";
    }

    // ETC

    // Create the prepared query
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users as u WHERE $where");


    if(isset($form["txtSalaryFrom"]) and is_numeric($form["txtSalaryFrom"])) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':txtSalaryFrom', $form["txtSalaryFrom"]);
    }

    if(isset($form["txtSalaryTo"]) and is_numeric($form["txtSalaryTo"])) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':txtSalaryTo', $form["txtSalaryTo"]);
    }

    if(isset($form["txtCompanyName"])) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':txtCompanyName', %.$form["txtSalaryTo"].%);
    }     
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: How will I do this for LIKE '%company%' when I do like '%:company%' I am getting following error. **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'company_name LIKE '%:company%'' at line 1'' at line 1**

Comment: if(isset($form["txtCompanyName"])) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':txtCompanyName', %.$form["txtSalaryTo"].%);
    }

Comment: I am doing exactly but for some reason it is still giving this error can you help me sort it out. if(!empty($company)) {$where = $where."AND company_name LIKE :company ";}  if(!empty($company)) {$companyFormat = "'%".$company."%'";$stmt->bind_param(":company",$companyFormat);}

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':company' at line 1

Comment: I found the solution I am using mysqli_connect object not PDO object but I dont want to switch to PDO object is there any way to prepare statement using mysqli instead of PDO in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
<?php

$company = $_GET['txtCompanyName'];
$experience = $_GET["txtExperience"];
$salaryFrom = $_GET["txtSalaryFrom"];
$salaryTo = $_GET["txtSalaryTo"];


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1 = 1 ';


if(!empty($company)){
    $sql .= " AND tablename.CompanyName LIKE %$company% ";
}

if(!empty($experience)){
    $sql .= " AND tablename.Experience = $experience ";
}
if(!empty($salaryFrom)){
    $sql .= " AND tablename.Salary > $salaryFrom ";
}
if(!empty($salaryTo)){
    $sql .= " AND tablename.Salary < $salaryTo ";
}
```

Also though, you should make sure you're protecting against SQL injection. Maybe use PDO and prepare http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I am receiving the following error for all inputs when doing through prepared statement **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':company' at line 1**

Comment: Try without pdo first. Just to see if you can get the query working.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at: [plinq](http://plinq.codeplex.com) [linqforphp](http://linqforphp.codeplex.com) [phplinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com)